# Doctrine2 $qb->expr method with arrays

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I use this code;

```
public function findConversation($users)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("c");
        $qb->leftJoin('c.users','u')
            ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('u', $users))
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleResult();
    }
```

But, $qb->expr method give a error;

> ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class bla bla
>   converted to string in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr.php
>   line 618

Which method easier for where condition work with array?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an array of user ids as the parameter.

*Code:*

```
$qb->expr()->in('u', array_map(function($user) { return $user->getId(); }, $users))
```